# What are these folders and files in my library folder?

Tags: finder, applications, malware, virus, library

I have several suspicious folders and files in my library folder.
And I was wondering if I should delete them.

- ApplicationaContents
- ApplicationContents
- ApplicationSupport

[image: applicationsupport]

- appn

this is just a file containing the word:

hydrometrid

- arracacha

[image: arracacha]

edit:
[image: Library]

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on what the application is.  There is too little context here to provide an answer.  Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible that the three other folders with application in it are just mispelled versions or are they actually used? What context can I provide to make things clearer?

Comment: Depends on what the parent folder is.  What is the application?  Most of this is set by the application itself.  Too little context to tell.  If you are really concerned, run a virus scan.  There are free scanners available for download.  Do that before deleting files that could break an application.

Comment: The parent folder is my system library.

Comment: It's very difficult to say...is what we are looking at a system using English or a different language?  (i.e. *Programme*) What you could be seeing is just the effects of mistakes made due to internationalization of software.  It's important to distinguish *why* you think they are suspicious in nature.

Comment: The system language is german. I think the appn and arracacha are suspicious because I don't get their purpose. A google search to their words brings me to potatos and some insect???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can’t be sure they are safe, make a backup and check you have a copy of the files and then delete them.

Library can be finicky when you delete something the system needs, but Application Support with a space is legitimate. The others you show in th image don’t come from Apple so they’re malware at worst or third party created at best.

Comment: You might want to add that if this is seen then: a) a possible 3rd party app of very dubious quality anyway did this; if, and b) this type behaviour is *very* typical for really malicious software  and c) [this](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/206261-chill-tab-malware/?page=3) might be worth a look in this case.